# Will this RAM work well in an iMac?

Tags: memory, imac

I want to increase the RAM of my 2.4GHz Intel Core 2 Duo 24" iMac. I currently have 1GB of RAM DDR2 SDRAM 667 MHz. I really want to upgrade, but know nothing about RAM or hardware in general... These are the cards I found: http://www.crucial.com/eu/store/mpartspecs.aspx?mtbpoid=D4B6F603A5CA7304

Are these of quality or should I look at something else? Finally, I have 800MHz of Bus speed, couldn't I get faster RAM?

Thanks for taking the time to read, and hoping you take the time to answer.

Comment: Since this question was just bumped to the front page: If you are on SuperUser again, please click the tick mark next to Martin's answer. This will mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Crucial and [OWC](http://www.macsales.com/) are two of the most known and valued Memory re-sellers for Mac (and other PCs as well). You can rarely go wrong with either.

The bus speed you have (800) is not the memory speed, it’s the front side bus speed. If you enter the exact model in Crucial memory configuration tool, it should give you all the possible RAM upgrades you can perform. Your model possibly uses 667 DDR2 and that is fine. Even if you could put 800 MHz memories, the difference will be negligible in a real life usage scenario.